# Grab SamAccountName from SIP attribute with Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory, syntax-error, export-to-csv

I am attempting to grab a SAMAccountName from a SIP address attribute in AD. I keep getting a syntax error that I just can't figure out. I have used similar code to grab a SAMAccountName using the employeeNumber attribute. I have to wonder if the "-" in the attribute name has anything to do with the syntax error.

```
Import-Csv -Path .\SIP.csv | ForEach-Object {
$sipGet = Get-ADUser -Filter "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress -eq $($_.'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress')" |
    select -Expand SamAccountName
$_ | select *,@{Name='SamAccountName';Expression={$sipGet}}
} | Export-Csv -Path .\SIP.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ADUser` does not know `-eq` as a filter. Instead, use plain equal sign, and wrap the string in escaped double quotes.

```
$sipGet = Get-ADUser -Filter "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress = \"$($_.'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress')\"" |
select -Expand SamAccountName
```

Should do. (Can't test right now, have no access to AD environment)

Comment: I'm getting a little farther now but getting:

Get-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'sip:example.user@domain.com'.